# Add auth to some methods of API resource routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to restrict access to the index resource so that people cant view all the submissions from a contact form.. is this possible to do via a route or what are people doing ?

Im using Laravel 5.2

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/api', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function(){

    Route::resource('contact', 'ContactFormController', ['except' => [
        'create', 'edit'
    ]]);  

});
```

Answer (score 3):

got it.. added this to the controller in question

```
function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth', array('only' => array('index', 'show')));
}
```